# How does pre-axiomatic geometry relate to axiomatic one?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

If geometry is something abstract how did historical mathematicians discover theorems within the same framework of axioms, although they were unaware of the axioms? And what is the relation of the newer axiomatic mathematics to the older axiomless medium, in which mathematical objects presumably exist?

Comment: Lots of words in each sentence but I'm having some trouble deciphering the philosophical question. Can you make this this clearer (perhaps by using less jargon)?

Comment: I'm having trouble deciphering the question, philosophical or not.

Comment: Notwithstanding that your post does not state a distinct and clearly stated question: Axiomatizing a mathematical theory is a task not in the beginning, but in the later phase when the theory has obtained a certain degree of maturity.

Comment: what? Cheers Jo Wehler

Comment: (Question was significantly improved since my and virmaior's previous comments).

Answer (score 1):

Presumibely, [geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_geometry) started with "concrete" objects : drawing picture and measuring forms.

See :

- [Thomas Little Heath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Little_Heath), [A History of Greek Mathematics](https://archive.org/stream/cu31924008704219#page/n143/mode/2up) (1921), pag 118-on.

But then, in some still not well understood way, it changed from the investigation on specific problems to *proof*. Some "hard" problems can be solved not by trial-and-error but with an "argument", i.e. with logical deduction.

Thus, emerged a new "tool" : the mathematical proof, and with it a new issue : what we have to rely on in order that the proof is corrcet ?

These are the building blocks of the [axiomatic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiomatic_system) : *logical rules* of deduction and true (or, at least, assumed as true) *axioms*.

See :

- [Árpád Szabó](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rp%C3%A1d_Szab%C3%B3), [The Beginnings of Greek Mathematics](https://archive.org/details/TheBeginningsOfGreekMathematics) (ed.or.1969)

and :

- [Reviel Netz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reviel_Netz), [The Shaping of Deduction in Greek Mathematics: A Study in Cognitive History](https://books.google.it/books?id=VwggGX0ORLkC&printsec=frontcover) (1999)

Comment: How did the concept of mathematical proof arise? It is conjectured that proof in mathematics arose in parallel with the necessity of proof at court. We find the necessity of argumentation and demonstration arising both in mathematics and in speech at court and at public congregations in Athens during the 5th century BCE.

Comment: @JoWehler - it seems a plausible reconstruction. See [Geoffrey E.R. Lloyd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._E._R._Lloyd)'s studies and Netz's book : "This book can be read on three levels: first, as a description of the practices of Greek mathematics; second, as a theory of the emergence of the deductive method [...]".

Answer (score 0):

Let's state a geometric statement: If I have a point A, and two more points B and C, all three points different, and I draw a line from A to B and a line from A to C, then unless point B is on the line A to C or point C is on the line A to B, the lines A to B and A to C meet at point A and have no other point in comment.

That statement doesn't require any knowledge of axioms. And in pre-axiomatic geometry, someone would have tried and succeeded to "prove" it in a non-formal way.

When we have this non-formal proof, there is an obvious question: What makes the deductions used in the proof valid? Are they all valid? Can we decide what is a valid deduction and what is not a valid deduction? These are difficult questions and would lead to the discovery of *formal proofs*.

Then people would figure out that there are certain things that they just assume, without proof. For example "if A and B are different points then there is exactly one straight line connecting A and B". That situation is quite unsatisfactory. So they would write down all the "assumed facts" and check which ones really must be assumed: They would try to find proofs for "assumed facts". If a proof is found then it isn't an "assumed" fact anymore, it is something that can be proved.

And then they called the remaining "assumed facts" axioms.

The mathematics hasn't really changed that much, except that people in axiomatic geometry know what they are doing, while in non-axiomatic geometry they didn't really know. So some proofs may have become invalid because it was found they didn't use valid deductions (they may have been replaced with valid proofs). Some "assumed facts" may have been proved and therefore were not needed as axioms.

It's like driving a car, and then learning how a car works and understanding what actually happens when you hit the gas pedal or the breaks. Sometimes it makes no difference, sometimes it makes a lot of difference, but you probably feel better knowing what you are doing and knowing that you can rely on it.